# how to cache multipledatasets? or get a slow asp.net page to run faster

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, caching

My page is loading to slowly, i am loading information from 2 giant dataviews, to get infromation about sales history, into a table. I am loading the information based on yesterdays sales/numbers. I want to cache the data, but how could i do it if my query depends on the year selected, and the information the user wants. I was thinking it would be best to cache the pages.

If you have any other recomendations to load or do this in a more effiecient manner please help.

**Help my put a parameter in instead of my dropdownlist.value in my query?**

```
 saocmd.Connection = conn
            conn.Open()

            If RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "Sales" Then
                saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales, B601SalesAsOF.Sales AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & ") AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
                Label2.Text = "Sales"
            ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "NetSales" Then
                saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, (ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFNET,0)+ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOfOTHer,0)) as AsOfSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, (ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YENET,0)+ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEOTHER,0)) as YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales, (ISNULL(B601SalesAsOF.NETSales,0)+ ISNULL(B601SalesAsOF.OtherSales,0)) AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & ") AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
                Label2.Text = "Net Sales"
            ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "INSSales" Then
                saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFINS,0) as AsOFSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEINS,0) as YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales,ISNULL(B601SalesAsOF.INSSales,0) AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & ") AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
                Label2.Text = "Insurance Sales"
            ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "CXSales" Then
                saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFCX,0)as AsOfSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, ISNULL(B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFCX,0) as YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales, ISNULL(B601SalesAsOF.CXSales,0) AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & ") AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
                Label2.Text = "Canceled Sales"
            End If

            'selects sql query
            'saocmd.CommandText = "SELECT B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.AsOFSales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.ASOFPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YESales, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.YEPAX, B603SalesAsOFMASTER.PCTofSales, B601SalesAsOF.Sales AS CurrentSales, B601SalesAsOF.PAX AS CurrentPAX FROM B603SalesAsOFMASTER INNER JOIN B601SalesAsOF ON B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR = B601SalesAsOF.SDESCR WHERE (B603SalesAsOFMASTER.DYYYY =" & DropDownList1.SelectedValue & ") AND (B601SalesAsOF.DYYYY = (year( getdate() ))) order by B603SalesAsOFMASTER.SDESCR"
            saoda.Fill(saods, "salesasoftable")

            'does the math for the Percent of PAX
            Dim pctofpax As New DataColumn
            pctofpax = New DataColumn("PCTPAX1", GetType(Decimal))
            pctofpax.Expression = "[ASOFPAX] / [YEPAX]"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(pctofpax)

            'does the math for the average per passanger
            Dim avgppax As New DataColumn
            avgppax = New DataColumn("AVGPAX", GetType(Double))
            avgppax.Expression = "CurrentSales / CurrentPAX"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(avgppax)

            'gets the projected sales by dividing the currentsales by the percent of sales
            Dim projectedye As New DataColumn
            projectedye = New DataColumn("ProjSales", GetType(Double))
            projectedye.Expression = "IIF([PCTofSales] = 0, [CurrentSales], [CurrentSales] / [PCTofSales])"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(projectedye)



            'gets the projected amount of passangers by dividing the current amount of passengers by the percent of pax
            Dim projectedyep As New DataColumn
            projectedyep = New DataColumn("ProjPAX", GetType(Double))
            projectedyep.Expression = "CurrentPAX / PCTPAX1"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(projectedyep)

            'gets the difference between projected sales and current sales
            Dim differencesales As New DataColumn
            differencesales = New DataColumn("remainingsales", GetType(Double))
            differencesales.Expression = "ProjSales - currentsales"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(differencesales)

            'gets the difference in projected passengers and current passengers
            Dim differencepax As New DataColumn
            differencepax = New DataColumn("remainingpax", GetType(Double))
            differencepax.Expression = "Projpax - currentpax"
            saods.Tables("salesasoftable").Columns.Add(differencepax)

            GridView1.DataSource = saods
```

Comment: Any idea where the bulk of the time is spent?  Is that in waiting for the dataset to be filled, or in some of the calculations?

Comment: I think a lot of the time spent is that when the query is called the views I have, are totaling all the information of tons of fields from the datawarehouse.

Comment: You **think** it's when the query is run? Have you looked at the execution plans?

Comment: no i will look at those and post back

Comment: i couldnt figure out where the exectuion plans were

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the string concatenation when building your select statement. This is hurting you in two ways:

- Leaves you open to SQL injection
- Floods the database server with different queries, forcing a hard parse every time

Use a **parameterized query** with placeholders instead, and set the parameter values based on the user's input.

Here's a short discussion:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html

Comment: using the parametrized query actually got my page running much faster

Answer (score 2):

**Your site is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)**.  I would look into fixing that before you do anything else.

With regards to the slowness, I would focus on how fast your query is running.  Can you provide us with an execution plan for a particularly slow query.  Right off the top I would say get rid of the `ORDER BY`.  You can do this on the client side...

Make sure you have the proper indexes in place.  Last you might look into passing the year in as a parameter (this last one is just a shot in the dark).

Comment: Based on the fact that the OP is making direct SQL statments from the presentation is an indication of experience. I would say that indexing is probably lacking and the best bang for the buck. And yes, any filtering you can do (passing in year as a parameter) will speed things up. +1

Comment: In addition I would suggest that the OP could offload a lot of this work from your client side code to the database using Views and Stored Procedures.  Client (meaning ASP.NET not JS) side code is probably not the best place to be doing all of this stuff.

Comment: my problem is getting the two views in a single stored procedure, i couldn't get it to work

Comment: You can query two views within a stored procedure.  If you are getting an error it's not because of a limitation of SQL Server.

Comment: ill post what i have, if you could help me it would be great

Comment: Should probably put it in a new post. Maybe reference this one from the new one.

Comment: it actually may get to messy up there, i am going to post it as a new question

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might not be with the database at all. If you are binding one million results to a DataGrid and you don't use paging, then thats just alot of HTML to shove down the pipe. If you are paging your resuls so that you are only "displaying" ten of the one million records returned from the Database, but you have ViewState enabled on the DataGrid, then all those records are being serialized and send to the browser anyway. Your best bet is to implement custom paging by only returning the ten (or 20, or 50) records you wish to display from the database.

[Check out this article on 4Guys about how to implement custom paging](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020140032/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/031506-1.aspx).

Comment: no the datagrid is small, there are only 14 rows and like 10 columns the problem is the information in the datagrid is all totals

Comment: You can also look at articles like http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/Data_Caching.aspx that will show you how to cache the results. You can use the parameters in your keys so you cache each result separately. This does require an intermediate layer abstration.

Answer (score 1):

The 2 salient facts I see here are:
(1) the bottleneck is reads from your OLTP database due to a complex query
(2) the data you need are somewhat old (yesterday) and not subject to change for the duration of the day.

I automatically think of using a datamart or data warehouse for a situation like this.  Overnight, you run SSIS jobs to refresh the datamart data, and then they are available for query when the execs arrive in the morning.  The datamart may be denormalized in order to improve query performance--in fact, it is typically encouraged.  I would be surprised if your query performance did not improve by at least an order of magnitude.  An additional benefit of this approach is that you will have all the reporting and analysis capabilities of SSAS at your fingertips.  There are execs who love being able to slice and dice the data in an analysis cube, so they might regard you as an IT rock star if you make this capability available to them.  Yet another advantage is that the data mart can be provisioned and managed separately from your OLTP database, which means that other users of your web app will not notice slow performance while these queries are going on.  A final advantage is that SSAS is really good at partitioning your data along known dimensions (for example, by year).

If you do not have sufficient bandwidth to set up a separate datamart/data warehouse, you could certainly do something similar within the confines of your OLTP database.  You would miss out on the SSAS capabilities and segregation of complex queries, but you could try to roll out the data mart in a future release.  One approach within your existing DB would be to set up indexed views, but those may impose a serious runtime cost due to the necessity of updating the view with every related data update.  Perhaps a better approach would be to simply create denormalized tables within your OLTP database with the specific mission of servicing these specialized queries.  Just schedule a job to run every night to refresh the tables.  You could even use SSIS for this, although it might be overkill if everything is happening within the confines of one DB.  A SQL statement or statements will probably suffice.

With either approach, I would suggest performing the calculations at the database level. I see no advantage to calculating these on the fly, as they will not change through the day.  Populating the calculated columns should be done as part of the overnight processing.

Comment: edited to reflect the fact that the amount of data returned by the queries is very small.

Comment: I would love to be able to do this but it sounds a little advanced for me at this moment, eventually i want to build a cube but for now im only working with sales and years, if you could give me more information i am higly interested.

Comment: Then go with the idea of setting up a separate denormalized table (or tables) within your DB.  Define the columns to be whatever is now in your dynamic views.  Don't worry about denormalization, because the table(s) will be updated only once a day by an overnight process.  Also, I would still recommend that the calculations go in the table, rather than being performed at the application layer.  The reason is that it's always a good idea to put everything about a process in a single location. Do you know how to schedule a job to run every night?

Comment: BTW, if you find my answer helpful, I'd be grateful for a vote. :)

Comment: Thanks for your help, i am going to try and put all the math in the query, i think i did it this way because i kept getting divide by 0 errors but i learned how to get around that.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I do not think that you have a SQL injection vulnerability, since the only user input involved in the query comes from a drop-down list.  As long as the only values available in the drop-down are set by the application, there should be no danger of malicious user data entry.

Comment: This is a web application. You do know that the user can change anything on the page before it gets posted, including the values of drop-downs?

Comment: I see what you're saying...the post can contain any arbitrary text for the DropDown1 control.  Good point.

Comment: I am going to try and use a parameter

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a Table with results for every year once and for all? Sounds like its historical data so should not change.

Migth not solve any performance issue but still unload some load.

Cheers,
Stefan

Comment: you think i should create a view for each year?

Comment: No, just create a result Table. If the results you are fetching are not changing you can create a table with the results. If for some reason the historical data changes you can just update the table if this is happening.